# Problem with JS function on Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

```
function getLast(tagNm) {
    /* This function search the last element
     * that use this tagName */
    var cont = 0;

    $.each(window.wdgList, function (index, value) {
        if (value != undefined) {
            if ($("#" + value).get(0).tagName == tagNm) {
                cont += 1;
            }
        }    
    });

    return cont;
}
```

And with all the browser-including IE- this function works perfect but with Opera doesn't, what could be wrong.

BTW, the error says this:

The mistake is this: Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById(value)' to object

Comment: What's `window.wdgList`? It's undefined in Opera and Chrome (at least for me).

Comment: What is the actual error you get? - Opera has a nice stack trace feature that should point out where the exact error is.

Comment: hotkey is: `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `O` (at least on windows) to bring up the console in Opera.

Comment: `value != undefined` is a destined to fail. Use this instead: `typeof value != 'undefined'`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I don't understand why that would be the case here. Seems like a simple check to see if the `value` parameter is set to `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Šime, Why is it destined to fail?  It's a formal parameter, not a global.  That said, I would prefer `!==` to `!=`.

Comment: Ok, window,wdgList is a variable that i create.

Comment: The mistake says this: The mistake is this: Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'document.getElementById(value)' to object

Comment: @patrick @Mike `undefined` is a global property and it's value is not safe

Comment: @hidura What code line is the error pointing to? I don't see `getElementById` in the above code.

Comment: It won't affect Opera vs others, but it's not a good idea to do a case-sensitive `tagName` comparison on an HTML document. Browsers typically upper-case the tag names, but not always.

Comment: I don't have it i was using jQuery i changed last night but opera still giving me the mistake with the getElementById, but i fixed it was a mistake on the element that i was looking for that it was undefined, the answer is below.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: A couple opinions on the matter. I tend to think that if someone is defining a variable named `undefined` somewhere in the scope chain, then they probably *should* have their code fail. Would be a good teaching moment. Also, even if that was the case, the test here is for `!=`, so the only way it would fail is if the `undefined` in the scope chain happened to have a comparable value. Anyway, I don't like throwing out useful techniques because of someone else's unadvisable coding practices. You and I wouldn't do that, so you and I should feel safe doing a comparison to `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick 1. When presented with two solutions, one of them being flawless, the other having a flaw, why would you even consider the flawed solution (regardless how insignificant the flaw is)? 2. If `undefined` is set to `false` or `0`, `value != undefined` fails on all falsy values, compared to the initial case where it only fails on `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick 3. There is a reason why Crockford is so exclusive. He works for a huge company and the code that he and his team produces is used by many people around the world. Consider the case where a third person uses your code. That person might set `undefined` to a different value. You want your code to work even for that person.

Comment: ...example of testing falsey values against null/undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/269Cf/

Comment: @patrick I don't think that I'm wrong about my 2. point: http://jsfiddle.net/p5D3e/

Comment: @patrick 1. But `value != null` gets the same job done, so `value != undefined` is not needed really. 3. But if you work for a large company, and your JavaScript code is hosted on the company's web-server, some third person (a private person, a partner company, an unrelated organization) might use your code. If your company has reputation, that could easily happen. Now, you don't want your code to fail for that third person, do you?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Ah yes, I misunderstood. I thought you meant if `value` is falsey. In that case, my response to point 2 would be to refer you to my response 1 & 3. ;o)

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, I do want it to fail. It is really really bad to redefine `undefined`, and I don't want to accommodate for every potential bad practice. Again, if you redefine `undefined`, it *should* fail, unless you have a specific purpose for doing it, in which case your fate is in your own hands. ;o) Regarding *"value != null gets the job done"*, good point. I'd use that, but I'm still not averse to comparing to `undefined`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Just want to say that I understand and respect the validity of your arguments, but we just have a little different philosophy. Let me ask one thing. Do you find it to be even a little bit contradictory that Mr. Crockford laments the fact that people think they don't need to know and understand javascript in order to use it, while at the same time recommending against valid practices for the purpose of accommodating those using js without knowing or understanding it? Just a thought.

Comment: @patrick It is important to understand that those recommendations are conditioned by the position that he's in. Yahoo is a TOP 5 web-site in the US, it contains a large amount of JS code, and possibly hundreds of JS programmers. It is only natural in such a environment to try to develop code conventions that ensure that the generated JS code is robust. For a large company, robustness is a top priority. The way Yahoo is doing this is, they exclude certain language features that are - under certain circumstances - problematical. This is obviously an extreme behavior ...

Comment: ... but, for a large company, understandable.

Comment: @patrick Another example would be Google. Someone once asked why google.com doesn't validate (in W3 validator). Google's answer was that making the code valid would increase the code size, which would lead to a slightly slower page load time. And for Google, performance is a larger priority than W3C validation.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, those are good examples. I completely respect the decision of any company, big or small, to define a set of guidelines within that company in such a manner that they feel will be of the greatest benefit. That said, it is an entirely different matter when giving advice outside that context. I guess I just personally don't like to see a perfectly legitimate practice thrown in its entirety for the sake of a specific case where it may make sense to avoid it.

Comment: @patrick I believe that Crockford is convinced that his recommendations are good in most contexts (if not all). Now, are they? One could write a book about that. (In fact, I would love to read such a book :))

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I think you're probably right about Mr. Crockford. Still seems to me to be developing coding practices centered around those of whom he laments. Anyway, yes that would be a very interesting (and probably at times frustrating) book to read. Thanks for the good discussion. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say with the info provided, but if for some reason Opera isn't finding one of your elements, then `.get(0)` will be `undefined`, and you'll be attempting to access the `tagName` property on `undefined` which will result in a `TypeError`.

You should perhaps check that an element was found first.

```
$.each(window.wdgList, function (index, value) {
    if (value != undefined) {
        var el = $("#" + value).get(0);
        if ( el && el.tagName == tagNm ) {
            cont += 1;
        }
    }    
});
```

This makes sure there's an element before doing `element.tagName`.